# query so slow in influxdb, how to improve the performance

Tags: java, database, influxdb, opentsdb

I use the influxdb java api to query records from influxdb
and found the performance not good
have set the query fields to tag
below is the sql and execution time in java
anybody know how to change or do sth for the query performance
thx!

```
> select count(*) from propRecords where devId='1000000005020009' and propKey='B_phs_V' and time >=1583424000000000000 and time <=1584028800000000000

        name: propRecords
        time                count_cmd count_propValue
        ----                --------- ---------------
        1583424000000000000 269632    269632

> select time,cmd,propKey,propValue from propRecords where devId='1000000005020009' and propKey='B_phs_V' and time >=1583424000000000000 and time <=1584028800000000000";

        execution time in java code：2813ms
        execution time in java code：2915ms
        execution time in java code：2721ms
        execution time in java code：2457ms
        execution time in java code：2506ms
        execution time in java code：2515ms
        execution time in java code：2746ms
        execution time in java code：2837ms
        execution time in java code：2417ms
        execution time in java code：2793ms
```

```
> select count(*) from propRecords where time >=1583424000000000000 and time <=1584028800000000000;

        name: propRecords
        time                count_cmd count_propValue
        ----                --------- ---------------
        1583424000000000000 1078393   1078393

> select time,cmd,propKey,propValue from propRecords where time >=1583424000000000000 and time <=1584028800000000000;

        execution time in java code：12539ms
        execution time in java code：11449ms
        execution time in java code：14092ms
        execution time in java code：11174ms
        execution time in java code：12074ms
        execution time in java code：11254ms
        execution time in java code：11331ms
        execution time in java code：12529ms
```

```
use below influx api to query:

InfluxDB.class

public QueryResult query(Query query) {
    return this.executeQuery(this.callQuery(query));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how invested you are in InfluxDB, but the performance of QuestDB is a *lot* better. https://questdb.io/ It supports full SQL for queries. I've been running queries against the 1.6B row NYC Taxi dataset and getting sub-second results on a `sum()` over all 1.6B rows.